# Ubuntu восстановление системы

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, восстановление

я чайник, на ubuntu буквально пару месяцев, ситуация такая: Ubuntu, попытался обновить системный python, в итоге, как я уже потом понял, из-за этого пошла куча ошибок. При попытке их как-то решить появлялись все новые. И в итоге перестали открываться настройки, из меню исчез терминал, большая часть приложений не открывалась. Переключился на tty через alt cntrl f, теперь обратно на среду рабочего стола (стоял Gnome) не переключается. При попытке что-то установить, обновить, сделать любую операцию с apt - выдеет кучу ошибок, ругается на зависимости.

Насколько я понимаю как то решить без переустановки системы это нельзя (если можно был бы очень признателен за любой совет). И оттуда следующий вопрос, как правильно, и вообще можно ли переустановить убунту и не потерять данные. Разбиений диска на разделы нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну если не будешь удалять раздел, то нет, данные не потеряются при переустановке. Но то, что ты не отбил `/home` в отдельный раздел - приводит тебя к ошибке на этапе проектирования. Я бы на твёом месте перенёс бы важное файло на отдельный физический носитель, переразбил бы винт с системой и залил бы файло обратно.